# Flatten nested lists Automapper

Tags: automapper, flatten

Trying to map the following

```
public class WorkPreferance
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Location> PreferedLocations { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
}
```

to the following destination ...

```
public class WorkingPreferenceViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
}
```

but I cant wrap my head around what should be the mapping deceleration .. 
so far i have this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Location, WorkingPreferenceViewModel>()
        .ForMember(d => d.LocationID, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.LocationID))
        .ForMember(d => d.LocationName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Description))
        .ForAllOtherMembers(o => o.Ignore());

    cfg.CreateMap<WorkPreferance, WorkingPreferenceViewModel>()
        .ForMember(d => d.LocationID, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.PreferedLocations))
        .ForMember(d => d.LocationName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.PreferedLocations))
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. You can't map a collection of anything to only one instance of that thing. Unless of course you do an aggregation of some kind or take a single instance from the collection. What should `LocationID` and `LocationName` really be when you are mapping `WorkPreference`?

Comment: You can when you want to flatten .. Like you do with SelectMany in LINQ..

Comment: Meaning for every Location entry i would like to create a new object of WorkingPreferanceViewModel...

Comment: If you are going to create a new `WorkingPreferenceViewModel` for each location in the list, why does the viewmodel itself contain a list of locations as well?

Comment: @MarioDS you're right that was an author mistake .. sorry for that .. i have edited the question ..

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid AutoMapper cannot do this. It can map single objects to single objects, and a collection of objects to a collection of objects.

What you want to do is map a single object to a collection of another object. I can't think of how you would use AutoMapper to achieve that.

But, I must say, I don't really understand why you have defined your viewmodel that way. Why would you repeat the `Id` and `Name` so many times? In what way does your proposed structure become more easy to process?

What I would do is create a `LocationViewModel`, and have `WorkingPreferenceViewModel` contain an `IEnumerable<LocationViewModel>`. That way you can map it easily with AutoMapper by creating maps between the objects and their respective view models. It will neatly take care of the fact that there is a collection in there.